# TypeError: must be str, not bytes: I dont know how to solve this problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

./decode_base64.py 5DA71B75B0921BEFA9F2C98A6FE61676D850BE78

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kali/MayasevenCTF/36_46esaB/./decode_base64.py", line 17, in 
data2 = bin(table_str.find(data))[2:].zfill(6)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

infile = open(sys.argv[1],'rb')

table_str="/+9876543210zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"
table=list(table_str)

x=""
while 1:
  data = infile.read(1)
  if data == "":
     break
  if data == "=":
     break
  data2 = bin(table_str.find(data))[2:].zfill(6)
  x+=str(data2)

mod = len(x) % 8
if mod !=0:
  div = len(x) / 8
  x = x[0:div*8]

out_file=open('out','wb')

i=0
while i < len(x):
  num_str = ""
  j=0
  while j < 8:
    num_str += x[i]
    i+=1
    j+=1
  num = int(num_str,2)
  out_file.write(chr(num))

out_file.close
```

I try to change it to rb and wb it still didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You're reading bytes:

```
infile = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
```

You wanted to read utf8 codepoints:

```
infile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
```

Comment: You should always specify an encoding when opening a file in text mode. UTF-8 isn't the default on every OS (e.g. Windows uses CP-1252).

Comment: It didnt write out anything in the files